# How does <input type="hidden" name.../> work with JSP Servlets

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets

I'm studying JSP and Servlets by reading a book and following some online tutorials. I'm totally new with web programming using JSP and Servlets.

I came across an example which I am trying to understand.

**index.html**

```
<form action="emailList" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />

    <label>Email: </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" required /> <br />
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" required /> <br/>
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" required /> <br />

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Join Now" id="submit" />

</form>
```

**EmailServlet.java**

```
public class EmailListServlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String url = "/index.html";

        //get the current action
        String action = req.getParameter("action");

        if(action == null){
            action = "join"; //default action
        }

        //perform action and set URL to appropriate page
        if(action.equals("join")){
            url = "/index.html"; //the join page
        }
        else if(action.equals("add")){
            //get parameters from the request
            String firstName = req.getParameter("firstName");
            String lastName = req.getParameter("lastName");
            String email = req.getParameter("email");

            //store data in User object and save User object in database
            User user = new User(firstName, lastName, email);
            UserDB.insert(user);

            //set User object in request object and set URL
            req.setAttribute("user", user);
            url = "/thanks.jsp"; //the thanks page
        }

        //forward request and response objects to specified url
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(req, resp);
    }
```

The thing I don't understand is the `IF-ELSE` part.

I read somewhere that the main purpose of using hidden `<input>` is to determine the state of a form. The way I understand it is that of, **a way to check if form fields (or parameters) are null or not**.

If that's the case, then what is the purpose of the `value="add"` attribute?

Because on `else if(action.equals("add"))` , `add` was used.

What could the `req.getParameter()` return ?

```
//get the current action
    String action = req.getParameter("action");
```

I'm asking because in the past I did some CRUD project on PHP where it used the ff to check if form has no null parameters.

```
if(isset($_POST['btnSave'])){

}

<form method ="POST" action="index.php">
        <label>First Name<input type="text" name="firstname" required></label>
        <br /><br />
        <label>Last  Name<input type="text" name="lastname" required></label>
        <br /><br />
        <input type = "submit" name="btnSave" value="Save" />
        <input type = "submit" name="btnSearch" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

Instead, in the last form example it used the `btnSave` (form button) instead of a `hidden input`.

I just don't see the point of using a `value="add"` and what `req.getParameter("action")` could return. Because it was used on the `IF-ELSE`

I'd appreciate any explanation.

Thank you.

Comment: req.getParameter("action") returns the value of action i.e. add

Comment: A hidden field is just like any input field. The difference is that it doesn't appear on the screen, and the user can't modify its value. Other than that, it allows submitting a request parameter just like any other field. In this case, it's used to tell the server what to do (add or join).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covering your questions in reverse order:

> What could the req.getParameter() return ?

It could return anything.  The `<form>` you posted will generate a request to the server that looks like this:

```
POST /emailList HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Cache-Control: no-cache

action=add&email=MyEmail&firstName=MyFirstName&lastName=MyLastName&submit=Join Now
```

Now, consider the case where someone submits the following request instead:

```
POST /emailList HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Cache-Control: no-cache

action=edit&id=1&email=NewEmail&firstName=TypoFreeName&lastName=TypoFreeLastName&submit=Update Details
```

Since you don't have an "edit" case in your servlet, but you do have that `if` check, your servlet will just redirect to /index.html instead of changing a user's details or inserting a new user.

A logical next step for code like this would be to add new sections to your servlet:

```
if(action.equals("join")){
    url = "/index.html"; //the join page
}
else if (action.equals("delete") {
    //Call UserDB.delete()
}
else if (action.equals("edit") {
    //Call UserDB.update()
}
else if(action.equals("add")){
    ...
}
```

> what is the purpose of the value="add" attribute?

It's partly to control the flow of your servlet and partly to act as an error prevention measure; if the request includes action=add, you proceed with the assumption that you'll have the other form elements (better practice would be to check to make sure that firstName, lastName, and email are set in the request before calling UserDB).

Comment: Thank you. Very well explained and I appreciate the example. It helped me understand it better. I have a question though, when you say that the better practice would be to check if parameters are set in the request, does it mean i have to do it on the EmailServlet.java file? Can you give a simple example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code is frankly a bit odd. It appears to be designed to handle the case where a **different** form (without an `action` field) is POSTed to the servlet, and to handle it by presenting the `index.html` page. Perhaps there's another form somewhere else in the chapter that does that?

If the form in the question is posted to the server, the servlet **will** receive an `action` parameter. (Well, unless JavaScript code actively removes the `input` from the form first.) So `getParameter("action")` will not return `null`. It might (if JavaScript code changed the `input`'s value) get a different string, even a `""` string, but not `null`.

It's probably worth noting that it *doesn't* handle the possibility that a different form *with* an `action=add` field is posted to the server, and happily uses the other parameters without checking them server-side, which is poor practice. Validation *must* be done server-side.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I haven't tried doing some validation yet but I get your point that it needs to be validated on the server side. By the way, when you say "Validation must be done server-side" do you mean that I need to add some IF-Else branch on my EmailServlet.java to check the parameters?

Comment: @p3ace: Yes, you need to check those other parameters to ensure they're valid before using them.